# Why did the entire staff of the Nevada Democratic Party quit after the Democratic Socialists won?

Tags: united-states, democratic-party, nevada

After Judith Whitmer, a Democratic Socialist, won her election to chair the Nevada Democratic Party, she received an email from Alana Mounce, the party's executive director congratulating her and which then went on to inform her that the entire staff, including consultants, were quitting.

Why?

Comment: Please add some sources.

Comment: @Martin Schoeder: It's easy enough to check with google ...

Comment: Yes, it is easy to check with google.  Perhaps you should do so and add some sources.  What I want to know is the articles that you have read, not the ones I can find.  I can't google to find out what you have read!

Comment: @James K: Any search engine besides Google will do  for example like Duck Duck Go. Why do you need to read the sources that I've looked at? Why do I need to "check" what I've already read? That's baffling. The information that is referred to in my question is correct as you've obviously found out.

Comment: @MoziburUllah it's useful to know what information you're aware of already and where the gap in your understanding is - in this example, the answer to your question is discussed in most articles on this event. Without knowing what you've already read, it's likely that an answer will just repeat that information, which presumably won't help you much.

Comment: @CDJB: I find it a bit creepy that you want to know what information that I'm already aware of. The point of references and sources surely is to verify the factuality of the claims made in the post. And like I've already pointed out, this is easily done with search engines for anyone who cares enough to want to check.

Comment: @MoziburUllah the point of references and sources in *answers* is definitely to back up the accuracy of claims made, however in *questions* showing what research you've done already is encouraged network-wide. It helps users more precisely answer your question. Feel free to post a question on [our meta site](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/) if you'd like a more detailed response.

Comment: @CDJB: like I've said, people can easily check the accuracy of claims made through search engines. The factual content of a question already shows to an informed citizen what degree of research has been done.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Consider this: If you hadn't read anything which includes the reasoning quoted below, then that quote is a good answer.  If you'd already read the The Hill article linked in the answer below and still had this question, then you'd be wondering about why the staff felt like quitting _en masse_ rather than being selectively (or broadly) fired was a good idea, and the answer doesn't help you at all.

Comment: @Bobson: My personal take on it is that the Democratic Party was trying to sabotage the Democratic Socialists of America, especially when taking into account that they had transferred most of the party funds out of the Nevada's Democratic Party coffers ...

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah: Haven't you just answered your own question?  The people who quit obviously don't want to support a Democratic Socialist.

Comment: @Jamesqf: That's my take on it, but I wouldn't say that this is an answer given that I don't know a great deal about the Democratic Socialists of America. I was hoping for a bit more context.

Comment: There is no requirement for posters to provide references for well-known or obvious facts. See [the discussion here](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/should-be-try-to-get-askers-to-include-references-in-their-questions). If you think something is unclear about a question, ask the poster to please clarify. Personally, in this case, I wouldn't because I think Mozibur Ullah's question is crystal clear.

Answer (score 11):

According to an anonymous source, Whitmer was planning to replace all the staff if she was elected.  So they quit before they could be fired.

> She said many times while running her campaign that it was her intention to clean house, to remove all the staff.

[Source](https://thehill.com/homenews/campaign/542337-nevada-democratic-party-staff-quit-after-sanders-backers-take-over)

Whitmer denies those claims, and says that the mass resignation is due to political differences: The Democratic Party staff in Nevada did not agree with her Democratic Socialist platform.

Comment: Why would they quit instead of being fired?  If fired, they could collect unemployment, and might have options of suing for wrongful termination &c.

Comment: @jamesqf: salaried white-collar employees rarely use the unemployment safety net. For one, they usually have ample savings to hold them over and ample connections for new salaried work; for another, it doesn’t look good on professional resumes.

Comment: @Ted Wrigley: Not necessarily true in my experience.  Indeed, when one startup I worked for (in Nevada, FWIW)  got shut down by the venture caps, they had people there that afternoon to get everyone signed up.  Certainly didn't affect my future employability :-)

Comment: @jamesqf A collective act of objection. I guess the staffs bid she won't be sat long on the post, so theirs chance to return, or even be promoted, is greatly enhanced if they chose to stay with the party leaders, and show loyalty.

Answer (score 5):

For decades, the Nevada Democratic Party was ruled by Harry Reid and his proteges, a bunch of tough centrists who waded through trade-union bureaucracy and greased a ton of palms to get every vote they could. When there was a better than fifty-fifty chance of the Democratic Socialists winning, the NDS transferred $450,000 from the NDS coffers to the Democratic Senatorial Campaign Committee, where Reid protégé Catherine Cortez Masto is running for Reid's old seat, and bailed.

While it can most certainly be seen as a case of sour grapes over being trounced, them fleeing the NDC is probably more about avoiding change. Grassroots fundraising and fundraising via knowing the right people and trading favors are two very different animals. So they scattered to other places within the larger DNC umbrella where they'd still be appreciated for their length of service and extensive contacts list, rather than having to change to being appreciated for how much fervor they can generate from common people.